# Getting different query results in SQL workbench and SQL-alchemy for distinct

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am working on SQL-alchemy for my application but when I use expression language to query results, I'm not able to get the same result as in SQL workbench

SQL - workbench query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(rule_id) FROM resultsdb.new_results where execution_id='2020-08-24 12:52:49.262783' and data_id='1T2C6';
```

Output:

```
['R03', 'R04']
```

SQL - alchemy query

```
engine.execute('use resultsdb')
conn = engine.connect()
executive_id='2020-08-24 12:52:49.262783'
data_id = '1T2C6'
conn.execute(text("SELECT DISTINCT(rule_id) FROM new_results WHERE execution_id=:x AND data_id=:y;"), x=executive_id, y=data_id).fetchall()[0]
```

Output:

```
('R03',)
```

I am not able to understand what is the issue.

Comment: did you try removing the [0] at the end of the function statement ??

Comment: Hi, added an answer to this, if it has solved, please mark it as solved to help other users.

Comment: Please note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were pulling the first element of the whole query set. Look below:

```
conn.execute(text("SELECT DISTINCT(rule_id) FROM new_results WHERE execution_id=:x AND data_id=:y;"), x=executive_id, y=data_id).fetchall()[0]
```

Only thing is to remove the index and you will have the full result.

```
conn.execute(text("SELECT DISTINCT(rule_id) FROM new_results WHERE execution_id=:x AND data_id=:y;"), x=executive_id, y=data_id).fetchall()
```